# Replacing all items between 2 values in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, macros, find-and-replace

I am working with a large text file in Notepad++ and want to remove multiple sections of text.

The text varies but always starts with `Note:` and always ends with `</IFRAME>`.

Is there a way of using find and replace to remove these blocks of texts knowing the start and end values?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide some sample text. Your question is missing important information (for example whether the text to be removed is spread over multiple lines, ...)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite easy. Open Find and Replace dialog box and in the *Search Mode*, select *Regular expression*.

In the *Find what* field, type: `Note:.*<\/IFRAME>`

You did not say whether the portions you want to replace contains line break or not. So, depending on your answer to this, check or uncheck "*. matches newline*"

[image: Search sample in Notepad++]

Comment: This will not work if there are more than 1 `</IFRAME>`.